# In list of dictionaries json format check particular word is available in value

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I wish to filter the list of dictionaries below, to get the `pg_no`s for all dictionaries whose `text` contains `valid`.

```
test_response = [
    {
        'title': 'some value',
        'pg_no': 1,
        'text': 'Data is not valid'
    },
    {
        'title': 'another title',
        'pg_no': 2,
        'text': 'some random text'
    },
    {
        'title': 'last title',
        'pg_no': 3,
        'text': 'valid data'
    }
]
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add there the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

The following comprehension works:

```
pg_nos = [d["pg_no"] for d in test_response if "valid" in d["text"]]
# [1, 3]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following code

```
    for i in test_response:
        if "valid" in i['text']:
            print(i['pg_no']) #Perform your required operation here I just used print for display
```

Or you can also use list comprehension like this

```
    [print(i['pg_no']) for i in test_response if "valid" in i['text']]
```

Comment: That comprehension produces `[None, None, ...]`. And if you use it for the side-effect of printing, that's even worse.